# matrix multiplication using a single pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I want to write a `c` code such that the child sends two matrix to the parent using pipes, the parent will then do the matrix multiplication and send the resulting matrix back to the child.
I know how to write this program using two pipes, but i want to know how to write this program using a single pipe.

Can anyone please provide the `c` code for the same?

Comment: Pipes are only one-way.

Comment: Just like I said, traffic in a pipe flows like a real pipe, and it flows in only one direction and can not flow in both. If you want traffic to flow in two directions you need two pipes.

Comment: You could reuse your pipe, but that comes with a whole slew of potential problems. Using two makes much more sense.

Comment: Child sends the first matrix through a pipe, let say p1. Parent can store the matrix, it has just received from the child. Now child sends the second matrix using the same pipe p1. Parent receives it and do multiply with the previously received matrix and sends the answer matrix again through the same pipe p1. So here, we used the single pipe (p1) to do the whole work. And at a time, pipe is flowing in one direction only. Tell me if there is any problem in this approach.
Please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes are not bi-directional.

Try sockets. Or use two pipes.

Comment: But is there any way we can write the code for this problem, using pipes ?

Comment: You already said in the question that you know how to do it with two pipes.

Comment: Yes,I know how to do it with 2 pipes. But i m asking how to do it with single pipe.

Comment: Can't be done. Pipes are not bi-directional.

Comment: A socket is like a bi-directional pipe. Try those.